# How to use a element with href property in combination with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, anchor

I want to use the `navigation.push(url)` functionality when clicking on an anchor tag element so that the app doesn't refresh by navigating to another page, and I can keep the application state.

The reason why I want to use this on an anchor tag element instead of a button is:

- to keep the native functionality to right click the element and copy the url
- to keep the url becoming visible when hovering over the element

When trying to use the combination as seen in the code below it still navigates towards a new page causing the webapp to refresh:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const TestComp = () => {
  const navigation = useHistory();
  return (
    <a
      onClick={() => {
        navigation.push(`/test`);
      }}
      href={`/test`}>
      this is a link
    </a>
  );
};

export default TestComp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`. It renders an anchor tag to the DOM and does all the linking/navigation for you that you are trying to do manually, and it doesn't reload the page.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const TestComp = () => {
  return (
    <Link to="/test">
      this is a link
    </Link>
  );
};

export default TestComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using event.preventDefault() it prevents the browser to execute the norma function of a event (click)... On anchor tag, it prevents the browser from navigating to another page, so that you can do it manually

```
<a
      onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        navigation.push(`/test`);
      }}
      href={`/test`}>
      this is a link
    </a>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. "Try this" answers do not help people learn, and it is much harder for people to see what is wrong when they come across an error. Please say what you have done to the code. It is very hard to understand what this code does.